# Chrome app install open site first run

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I want to after you install the application start automatically open page, how to do it?

My code

manifest.json

```
  {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CNN",
  "version": "2.1",
  "permissions": ["webview", "pointerLock", "geolocation", "videoCapture"],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

main.js

```
'use strict';
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    window.open("https://google.com/");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different listener: [chrome.runtime.onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onInstalled) and [chrome.browser.openTab](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser) (since Chrome 42):

- manifest.json: add `"browser"` to `"permissions"`.
- background script:

  ```js
  chrome.app.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
      chrome.browser.openTab({url: 'https://www.example.com'});
  });
  ```